# How to auto-scale a sagemaker async endpoint between 0 and n based on "HasBacklogWithoutCapacity"

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, aws-auto-scaling

I'm relatively new to AWS, and am trying to understand how (if its possible) to configure a model using an `async endpoint` to scale up from 0 instances when there are no requests to 1 or more instances when a request arrives, then shutdown. Also ideally if a second request arrives then scale up another instance up to n.

I'm trying to compare `async inference` with `batch inference`, I have large jobs that need processing periodically on demand. I've not yet decided which to go with - I'm fairly confident I have a good understanding of `batch inference` and I have `async inference` working but am struggling with auto-scaling.

I think I have the process of using the API to `register-scalable-target` and 1put-scaling-policy`and when I use`application-autoscaling describe-scaling-activities` I can sometimes see it scaling in and out but I cannot get it to do what I want.

I've played with a few options, but currently I have:

```json
    TargetTrackingScalingPolicyConfiguration={
        "TargetValue":1.0,
        "CustomizedMetricSpecification": {
            "MetricName": "HasBacklogWithoutCapacity",
            "Namespace": "AWS/SageMaker",
            "Dimensions": [{"Name": "EndpointName", "Value": endpoint_name}],
            "Statistic": "Maximum",
        },
        "ScaleInCooldown": 0,
        "ScaleOutCooldown": 30
    }
```

Edit: I've learnt now that you can monitor using cloudwatch under alarms and have changed the question. Now that I've found that I have a better understanding - but  the time it takes for the alarms to trigger is excessively long for what I'm trying to achieve.

There are two alarms for scale in and scale out:

```
HasBacklogWithoutCapacity
HasBacklogWithoutCapacity < 0.45 for 15 datapoints within 15 minutes

HasBacklogWithoutCapacity
HasBacklogWithoutCapacity > 0.5 for 3 datapoints within 3 minutes
```

So how does it determine 15 minutes for the first and 3 minutes for the second alarm (and more importantly how do I reduce this)? I don't really mind it taking a while to scale from 1 to 0, but I'd like it to scale from 0 to 1 as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/application/userguide/application-auto-scaling-target-tracking.html#target-tracking-considerations), "A target tracking scaling policy is more aggressive in adding capacity when utilization increases than it is in removing capacity when utilization decreases.", which would explain the behavior of how fast it scales up vs down.

Since you wanted to scale instances proportionally with number of requests, you should look into [step scaling policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/application/userguide/application-auto-scaling-step-scaling-policies.html#as-scaling-steps), which will allow you to "choose scaling metrics and threshold values for the CloudWatch alarms that trigger the scaling process as well as define how your scalable target should be scaled when a threshold is in breach for a specified number of evaluation periods".

In this case, you wanted to scale from 0 to 1 as quickly as possible, so you would just minimize the number of evaluation periods. (consider if outliers triggering scaling is a concern based on resources at hand, likelihood/frequency of outliers, etc.)

Comment: That first comment seems to come from the asymmetry of the 2 alarms that are created to manager the step-in/step-out. I guess its somewhere in the docs but I've not found it yet, I got a response from re:Post though confirming that "A target tracking scaling policy will create 2 CloudWatch alarms (one for high and one for low usage), which you'll be able to see in the CloudWatch alarms console. The high usage policy needs to have 3 consecutive 60 second breaching datapoints to trigger a scale-out; and the low alarm needs 15 consecutive 60 second breaching datapoints to scale-in"

Comment: They then made the same suggestion to use step-scaling, specifically "You may instead want to use step scaling policies, where you are able to create and control the alarms as well as the policy settings"

Comment: So I read that as "you cannot control the alarms using target tracking, only the policy"

Comment: Yeah the way I interpreted the design of autoscaling is target is supposed to be used out-of-the-box/as-is, so it's simple to use and generalizes well, whereas step scaling is more specialized and customizable for each individual use case.

Answer (score 0):

Close monitoring of the cloudwatch alarms indicates that "> 0.5 for 3 datapoints within 3 minutes" means a 3-minute rolling window is applied to `MAX(HasBacklogWithoutCapacity) and the sample rate appears to be 1 sample/minute. So when HasBacklogWithoutCapacity is >0 then this triggers after 3 minutes and a new instance is provisioned.

Similarly `HasBacklogWithoutCapacity` must be zero for a 15-minute window rolled of 15 samples for an instance to be shut down.

I've not paid to much attention to the cooldowns as I don't think they have much effect when the capacity is 0-1

I'd still be interested in knowing if the 3/15 minutes and 3/15 samples is configurable.